# How to extract values of an attribute in xml file using python , if attribute occurs multiple times with different values

Tags: python, xml

I have the below scenario where I have to extract attribute call `"dlFrequencyNumber"` with a particular value "10640" from an xml file, but  the attribute `"dlFrequencyNumber"` occurs in  multiple lines with different values,

`getElementsByTagName()` did not help as it always looks for the first occurrence.

I could do it with  the help of a for loop by iterating over all the lines , but is there any alternate way to do it. please suggest.

```
 '''
 <attributes>
 <dlFrequencyNumber>10615</dlFrequencyNumber>
 <dlFrequencyNumber>10640</dlFrequencyNumber>
 <dlFrequencyNumber>10665</dlFrequencyNumber>
'''
```

Thanks much!!

Vish

Comment: `dlFrequencyNumber` is an Element not an Attribute. If you know the value (10640) why you need to search for it?

Comment: my requirement is to change the value of this particular element dlFrequencyNumber.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Try this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

VALUE_REPLACEMENT = '999'
VALUE_TO_REPLACE = '10640'
xml = '''<attributes>
 <dlFrequencyNumber>10615</dlFrequencyNumber>
 <dlFrequencyNumber>10640</dlFrequencyNumber>
 <dlFrequencyNumber>10665</dlFrequencyNumber>
 </attributes>'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)

found = [freq for freq in root.findall('dlFrequencyNumber') if freq.text == VALUE_TO_REPLACE][0]
found.text = VALUE_REPLACEMENT
print(ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf8', method='xml'))
```

Comment: i'm facing problem while creating element object with fromstring method.in my scenario im opening and reading an xml file as a string into a varialble ie, str = open(file).read() then trying root = ET.fromstring(str) but this does not return the  entire content of the actual str variable.  but the code is working fine if i am directly assigning value to str like you did in the above code.

Comment: `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('country_data.xml')
root = tree.getroot()` this is how you should read it from file

Comment: import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('myxmlfile')
root = tree.getroot()
print(len(root))  i have tried this and it is printing the len of the root as only 1 . looks like the whole xml file is not getting parsed .